# Java - A modeless waiting dialog with dynamic text

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I need to create a dialog (message) box with the following requirements:

1. It should be able to change it text during it visibility period by adding periodically 1 dot to the current text it displays.
2. It should be modeless to avoid blocking the work of the main process. It is only a notification message for the user that a work is being processed.
3. It should be displayed when the process starts and disappeared when it ends. I don't mind to call it explicitly becuase I don't know how much time the task will take in advance.
4. The dialog should be displayed several times, each time with a different base text.

   I have tried to create a modeless dialog like this:

   ```
       try{
     String laf = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName(); 
     UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf); // tell the UIManager to change the look and feel
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     System.out.println("Unable to change look and feel");
   }   

   m_optionPane = new JOptionPane(a_sText, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[]{}, null);


   m_dialog = new JDialog();
   m_dialog.setSize(200, 50);
   m_dialog.setTitle(a_sTitle);
   m_dialog.setModal(false);
   m_dialog.setContentPane(m_optionPane);
   m_dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   m_dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
   m_dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
   m_dialog.pack();


   public void showDialog(String a_sText, boolean a_bDynamic){

   if(a_bDynamic){
       m_runnable = new DynamicWait(m_optionPane, a_sText);

       m_thread = new Thread(m_runnable);

       m_thread.start();
   }else{
       m_optionPane.setMessage(a_sText);
   }

   m_dialog.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void hideDialog2(){

   if (m_thread != null){

       m_thread.interrupt();

       m_runnable = null;
       m_thread = null;
   }

   m_dialog.dispose();
   ```

   }

   and then use a thread to constantly add the dots..

   ```
   public class DynamicWait implements Runnable {

   public DynamicWait(JOptionPane a_optionPane, String a_sText){

   Log4jWrapper.writeLog(LogLevelEnum.WARN, "DynamicWait - " + a_sText + " Thread ID " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

   m_optionPane = a_optionPane;
   m_sText = a_sText;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {

   while(m_bRun){

       try {
           m_optionPane.setMessage(m_sText);
           Thread.sleep(1000);
           m_optionPane.setMessage(m_sText + ".");
           Thread.sleep(1000);
           m_optionPane.setMessage(m_sText + "..");
           Thread.sleep(1000);
           m_optionPane.setMessage(m_sText + "...");
           Thread.sleep(1000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {

           Log4jWrapper.writeLog(LogLevelEnum.WARN, e.getMessage());
       }
   }
   ```

   }

   public void stopRun(){
        m_bRun = false;
       }

   Well, all in all, I couldn't get the proper results.

   I'll appreciate your advise.

   Thank you.

Comment: `Well, all in all, I couldn't get the proper results.` - well what results do you get? You listed 4 requirements. Do you get any of the 4, zero of he 4?

Comment: *"..by adding periodically 1 dot to the current text it displays."*  What is this, the 1980s?  That may be an appropriate way to indicate progress in an app. based around the command line, but for GUI development, we have progress bars!

Comment: camickr - It shows me a dialog that contains the text of all the texts all together alternating rapidly. Also, I guess for the same reason, the dots are not progressing orderly. Thanks.

Comment: Andrew, I must say that Swing is very new for me. So, maybe you can give me a pointer how to implment your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Tip: Add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: *"So, maybe you can give me a pointer how to implment your suggestion."*  See [How to Use Progress Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) & [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.